# In Node.js, when is data stored on the heap?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

In C you explicitly ask for and manage memory on the heap, so interaction with the heap is well defined/apparent. How do you reason about this in Node.js?

Sub-questions:

- where/how are functions stored?
- are there certain objects/primitives that always get stored on the heap? (e.g. buffers)
- does data migrate from the stack over to the heap? when?

References to good resources on this subject would also be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: An answer to this would definitely be helpful in locating possible memory leaks during development. Nice question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about stack vs heap nor about freeing memory. It happens automatically since Node.js offers a precise tracing garbage collector. Some data is stored in GC heap. Some data is on the stack. You can't generally tell because it depends on optimisations performed by the JIT-compiler at runtime. Profiling tools might provide application-specific insight.

As for resources other than memory (e.g. files and sockets), use `finally`:

```
var file = open(…);
try {
    …
} finally {
    close(file);
}
```

Comment: I think what you meant to say is "You **shouldn't** care about stack vs heap"... obviously some people do care, otherwise this wouldn't be a question.

Comment: @rightfold I'm more interested in conceptualizing how the runtime might go about making these decisions in order to understand/acknowledge it during development. Obviously you can treat it as a black box, but I think an understanding of this should be useful to most Node.js developers.

Comment: It's completely possible to have memory leak in js with, for example, dangling callbacks, global variables, DOM component management.